# Trouble with Django annotation with multiple ForeignKey references

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm struggling with annotations and haven't found examples that help me understand. Here are relevant parts of my models:

```py
    class Team(models.Model):
        team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    class Match(models.Model):
        match_time = models.DateTimeField()
        team1 = models.ForeignKey(
            Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_team1')
        team2 = models.ForeignKey(
            Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_team2')
        team1_points = models.IntegerField(null=True)
        team2_points = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

What I'd like to end up with is an annotation on the Teams objects that would give me each team's total points. Sometimes, a team is `match.team1` (so their points are in `match.team1_points`) and sometimes they are `match.team2`, with their points stored in `match.team2_points`.

This is as close as I've gotten, in maybe a hundred or so tries:

```py
teams = Team.objects.annotate(total_points = 
Value(
  (Match.objects.filter(team1=21).aggregate(total=Sum(F('team1_points'))))['total'] or 0 + 
  (Match.objects.filter(team2=21).aggregate(total=Sum(F('team2_points'))))['total'] or 0, 
  output_field=IntegerField())
)
```

This works great, but (of course) annotates the `total_points` for the team with pk=21 to every team in the queryset. If there's a better approach for all this, I'd love to see it, but short of that, if you can show me how to turn those '21' values into a reference to the outer team's pk, I think that will work?

EDIT: I ended up using a combination of elyas' answers and annotating a raw SQL statement to solve my issues. I was not able to keep normal annotations from dropping non-unique scores from the queryset, but raw SQL seems to work.

Here's that raw annotation:

```py
teams = Team.objects.raw('select id, sum(points) as total_points from (select team1_id as id, team1_points as points from leagueman_match union all select team2_id as id, team2_points as points from leagueman_match) group by id order by total_points desc;')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution to annotating the QuerySet might be to make `total_points` a `@property` of the `Team` model (depending on the use case):

```py
from django.db.models import Case, Q, Sum, When


class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def total_points(self):
        return Match.objects.filter(Q(team1=self.id) | Q(team2=self.id)).aggregate(
            total_points=Sum(Case(
                When(team1=self.id, then='team1_points'),
                When(team2=self.id, then='team2_points')
            ))
        )['total_points']
```

The disadvantage is that it can't be used in subsequent QuerySet operations e.g. `.values()`, `.order_by()`.

Django also has a [`@cached_property` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) which will cache the output of the attribute when it is first called.

#### Other solutions tried

Originally I thought you could leverage the reverse relations `match_team1` and `match_team2` from the `Team` model to generate a simple annotation:

```py
teams = Team.objects.annotate(
    total_points=(
        Sum('match_team1__team1_points', distinct=True)
        + Sum('match_team2__team2_points', distinct=True)
    )
)
```

Unfortunately this solution encounters difficulties in handling duplicates. The `distinct=True` argument eliminates the issue of points from the same match being summed more than once. But it introduces a different issue where different matches with the same points scored will be excluded.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in, here. I thought the magic of reverse relations should help, too, but this doesn't seem to work...I get 'None' for every team's `total_points` value. If I run just this:

````
teams = Team.objects.annotate(total_points=(
        Sum('match_team1__team1_points')))
````

...then the teams with match_team1 matches get their points. I didn't (but can, if it's helpful) verify their point totals found this way are accurate.

Comment: Oof. Comment formatting (and time limit?) got me. Sorry for the ugly.

Comment: Some minor progress, I guess. The following annotation gets 'almost' all the scores right. The remaining problem is that if a team has the same score in multiple matches, the duplicate scores are ignored and their overall total is reported too low. 

`teams = Team.objects.annotate(t1_points=Coalesce(Sum('match_team1__team1_points', distinct=True),0),t2_points=Coalesce(Sum('match_team2__team2_points', distinct=True),0),total_points = F('t1_points') + F('t2_points')).order_by('-total_points')`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't replicate your error of returning `None`'s. The code I posted works for the small dataset I created to test with (which covers the various combinations, as well when as the `_points` fields are `None`). I can't quite figure out why it wouldn't be working for you.

Comment: This subset that works for you - `teams = Team.objects.annotate(total_points=( Sum('match_team1__team1_points')))` - returns the correct totals on my end.

Comment: I added the SQL query that's generated on my end to my answer. It might help debug the issue if there's any differences. FYI I'm using Django 3.2.2 and SQLite.

Comment: I still had trouble with same-value scores being dropped by that `distinct` clause, but your suggestion about adding a `@property` is a great help and solves some other issues I had coming up. The downside of the `@property` solution is that I can't filter or order by it, but appending with raw SQL works around that. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the SQL again - you're right. There's a big issue with the `DISTINCT` clause here because it's applied to the `points` fields - we'd need a more accurate `SELECT` first. And even though I can see the issue I can't think of a good Django solution to that. There's the `Subquery` and `OuterRef` utilities but I haven't seen that used with aggregations. I'll edit my answer to clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I would advice to refactor your data model. Even if you find a solution for this specific problem, you may want to think little ahead.
This is a solution:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Match(models.Model):
    match_time = models.DateTimeField()
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_team1')
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_team2')

class Points(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(
        Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match')
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='team')
    points = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

With this you can sum up easily the points of any team, and also filter it by matches.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could change the models, but at this point I'm stuck with what I have to work with.